# Let $E/ \Bbb{C} $ be an elliptic curve which has CM over $\Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-5})$. Then, why $j(E)$ is real number?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, complex-multiplication

Let $E/ \Bbb{C} $ be an elliptic curve which has CM over $\Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-5})$.
Then, why $j(E)$ is real number?

If theory of complex multiplication is well known, we can explicitly calculate $j$ invariant of $E$, but ''Advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves'' written by Silverman reads $j(E)$ is real number is easy in this situation.

What is a easy way to prove $j($)$ is real number in this situation ?

Comment: Hint for the curve with CM by the full ring of integers: if $\tau$ is in the upper half-plane, $j(-\overline{\tau})=\overline{j(\tau)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"has CM over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$" is ambiguous please don't use it. An elliptic can have CM by $\Bbb{Z}[n\sqrt{-5}]$ but not by $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ (try $E \cong \Bbb{C}/\Bbb{Z}[7\sqrt{-5}]$)

If $E$ has CM by $O_K$ then $E$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}/I$ where $I$ is an ideal of $O_K$.

$\overline{I} = \{ a \in O_K,\overline{a}\in I\}$ is an ideal as well.

Then $j(E)$ is real iff $j(\Bbb{C}/\overline{I})=j(\Bbb{C}/I)$ iff
$\Bbb{C}/\overline{I} \cong \Bbb{C}/I$ iff $\overline{I}$ is in the same ideal class as $I$.

Comment: Why your first 'iff' holds ? I think that is the problem here.

Comment: Write $I = a\Bbb{Z}+b\Bbb{Z}$ so $\overline{I} = \overline{a}\Bbb{Z}+\overline{b}\Bbb{Z}$. What is $j(\Bbb{C}/I)$ and $j(\Bbb{C}/\overline{I})$ ? @buoyant

Comment: I think they are the same because the lattice are homothetic.

Comment: Is your last condition $I$ and $ \overline{I}$ are in the same ideal class means $ \tilde{I}^2=1$ in $Cl(O_K)$ ? Why ?

Comment: @buoyant Please be more explicit on what you don't follow.

Comment: Exrcise in Silverman's book reads $j(E_I)=j(E_{ \overline{I}})$ iff only if $\tilde{I}^2=1$ in $Cl(O_K)$・・・①, but your last condition seems not to be equivalent to ① to me. Why your last condition $ \Bbb{C}/I \cong \Bbb{C}/ \overline{I}$ is equivalent to ① ?

Comment: It is for ideals in imaginary quadratic fields